# How does DataFrame produce this result?

Tags: python, pandas

Step 1: display the first 10 rows:

```
In [13]: data[:10]
Out[13]: 
   admit  gre   gpa  rank
0      0  380  3.61     3
1      1  660  3.67     3
2      1  800  4.00     1
3      1  640  3.19     4
4      0  520  2.93     4
5      1  760  3.00     2
6      1  560  2.98     1
7      0  400  3.08     2
8      1  540  3.39     3
9      0  700  3.92     2
```

Step 2: list all rows that has a rank of 1

```
 In [15]: data["rank"]==1
    Out[15]: 
    0      False
    1      False
    2       True
    3      False
    4      False
    5      False
    6       True
    7      False
    8      False
    9      False
    10     False
```

Step 3: Produce list of rows with rank=1

```
In [16]: data[data["rank"]==1]
Out[16]: 
     admit  gre   gpa  rank
2        1  800  4.00     1
6        1  560  2.98     1
11       0  440  3.22     1
12       1  760  4.00     1
14       1  700  4.00     1
19       1  540  3.81     1
25       1  800  3.66     1
26       1  620  3.61     1
29       0  520  3.29     1
```

I don't understand step 3. Why does data[boolean] produce the actual rows with rank==1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[boolean]` where `data` is a dataframe and `boolean` is some sequence of boolean values means: align `boolean` index with `data` index and pick `data` values where corresponding `boolean` value is `True`. If `boolean` has an index it has to match one-to-one, if it does not it has to have the same length.

So you can for example pick the first value in your dataframe with a vector of `[True, False, ..., False]`

```
>>> data[[True] + [False] * 9]
    admit   gre     gpa     rank
0   0   380     3.61    3
```

If `boolean` does not have the same length e.g.

```
>>> data[[True] + [False] * 10]
```

you get a

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 11 instead of 10.
```

If `boolean` has an index which does not match you get an `IndexingError`

```
>>> data[(data["rank"] == 1)[:9]]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer
```

If you change the index names

```
>>> (data["rank"] == 1).add_prefix('_')
_0    False
_1    False
_2     True
_3    False
_4    False
_5    False
_6     True
_7    False
_8    False
_9    False
Name: rank, dtype: bool
```

you also get an error:

```
>>> data[(data["rank"].add_prefix('_') == 1)]
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer
```

This is known as [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). There is also indexing based on [label](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label), `data.loc[]` (which can be numerical or string-like or date-like) or absolute [position](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position), `data.iloc[]`, and a legacy method `data.ix[]` which was used for both of these.

Answer (score 1):

Because it acts as a mask.
Check this out [pandas reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking)